# select products ALL coming from same supplier region

Tags: sql-server

So i want to display product codes of products that their suppliers are ALL coming from the same region.Can you help me with that query?
tables are like that aproximately

```
 **supplier**
    ----------------------------------------
    supplier_code|  region   |   
    ----------------------------------------
e1               1         
e2               2
e3               1



 **product**
    ----------------------------------------
    product_code|  price   |   
    ----------------------------------------
    e1               1         
    e2               2
    e3               1

   **supply**(relationship)
    ----------------------------------------
    supplier_code|  product_code   |   
    ----------------------------------------
    e1               e1         
    e2               e2
    e3               e1
```

so far i got this but i dont know how i can have all suppliers of one product coming only from one region

```
SELECT product.product_code

FROM  product,supplier,supply

WHERE product.product_code=supply.product_code 

AND supplier.supplier_code=supply.supplier_code

GROUP BY supplier.region
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: What does group by do? And don't use comma-join syntax. Use explicit JOIN syntax instead.

Comment: @Strawberry i think that Group by may be wrong, but my main problem is that all suppliers of a product must come from same region
my professor only teached me this kind of syntax and it worked so far so dunno..

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query. The innermost query gets the number of regions for each product. Then it selects those that have only one region.

```
select X.product_code from 
(
    select supply.product_code,
    dense_rank() over (partition by product_code order by region) rank
    from supply
    inner join supplier on supply.supplier_code = supplier.supplier_code
) X
GROUP BY X.product_code
HAVING MAX(rank) = 1
```

Comment: Sry - didn't spot that this was M$SQL

Comment: Well done, I didn't realise that was what he wanted.  I do think the odds of him understanding this code are low.  Hopefully he googles and works out why this does what it does.

Comment: i will try to adjust this to my more complicated schema but this seems to be quite right!Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something as you are not explicit about the fields you want to return, and your query only gives the `product_code`. If you want to know the region they come from that needs to be in your `SELECT`.

You only need to join between the `Supplier` and `Supply` tables if you don't need the price of a product.

```
SELECT Supply.product_code, Supplier.region 
FROM  Supplier 
INNER JOIN Supply 
  ON Supplier.supplier_code = Supply.supplier_code
GROUP BY Supply.product_code, Supplier.region
```

Gives the result:

```
PRODUCT_CODE  REGION
e1            1
e2            2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1bd73/4)